Native apps not showing images after upgrade Expo 50 SDK
I have recently upgraded my React Native app from SDK46 to SDK50 and migrated from Webpack to Metro bundler. However, after building the iOS app, I noticed that none of the app's images, both internal and external, are showing up. Strangely, the web version of the app is not experiencing any image-related issues and all the images are showing up as expected.

Can you share a code example?

@MichaelBahl The problem is caused by this.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/42234
